# Which port is used by Service Fabric local cluster to connect to external services (e.g., Azure Blob Storage)?

Tags: .net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-service-fabric

Our corporate firewall is blocking Service Fabric local cluster traffic. Which port is used to connect to external services? Can it be changed from the clusterManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The ClusterManifest is used to define the cluster configuration for opening ports for ApplicationPorts(inbound traffic) and EphemeralPorts(mostly for Outbound), the ports you register there will be valid for the nodes only, if you have an extra layer of firewall or network systems and proxies, it won't work properly until you configure everywhere.
see more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-manifest#endpoints-used-to-configure-the-node-types). A quick description from the link:

> **EphemeralPorts** override the dynamic ports used by the OS. Service
>   Fabric uses a part of these ports as application ports, and the
>   remaining are available for the OS. It also maps this range to the
>   existing range present in the OS, so for all purposes, you can use the
>   ranges given in the sample JSON files. Make sure that the difference
>   between the start and the end ports is at least 255. You might run
>   into conflicts if this difference is too low, because this range is
>   shared with the OS. To see the configured dynamic port range, run
>   netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp.
>
> **ApplicationPorts** are the ports that are used by the Service Fabric
>   applications. The application port range should be large enough to
>   cover the endpoint requirement of your applications. This range should
>   be exclusive from the dynamic port range on the machine, that is, the
>   ephemeralPorts range as set in the configuration. Service Fabric uses
>   these ports whenever new ports are required and takes care of opening
>   the firewall for these ports.

.

Azure Storage Uses HTTPs for communication, the port you will need is 443, should be a default rule on firewall, you shouldn't need any configuration for this to work.

Below is some ports you may need:

- Azure SQL: 1433
- Azure Service Bus:  9350 to 9354, 5672, 443
- Azure Blob Storage: 80 and 443

[This link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2012/02/07/azure-ports/) contains a list of ports you may need to configure for other services

If your servers are behind a proxy, to connect to external servers you will need to configure the proxy settings before you reach external servers.

On dot net, the common approach is setting via config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.net> 
     <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"> 
       <proxy usesystemdefault="true" /> 
     </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

It will use the windows defined proxy settings, it should work on most cases, but depending on how and which libraries your are using, they might not use the default network settings, in this case you might need to set via code.

Comment: thank you.  The port 443 is open, but I still receive connection timeout. Also Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer is not working without defining the proxy server and port to use.

Comment: if your network has a proxy to connect to the internet, you have to configure it on your applications otherwise won't have access to the internet. I've some extra info.